# What is the proper way to remove a key-value pair in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, dictionary, key-value

I conducted the following experiment, and discovered that 'delete' can be used to remove a key-value pair. My question is: is this the 'proper' way to do it?

```
let myMap:{[key:string]:string} = {};

myMap["hello"] = "world";
console.log("hello="+myMap["hello"]); // it prints 'hello=world'

delete myMap["hello"];
console.log("hello="+myMap["hello"]); // it prints 'hello=undefined'
```

Comment: `delete myMap["hello"];` is correct, I don't see any problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is: is this the 'proper' way to do it?

This is the accurate way of doing it, but there are [two caveats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

- **unless the property is non-configurable**
- property is *inherited*

**For example** you cannot delete `href` property of `location`

```
delete location.href //returns false since this property cannot be deleted
```

**Demo**

```js
var b = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
};
Object.defineProperty(b, "c", {
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: false,
  writable: true,
  value: 3
});
delete b.c;
console.log(b); //all properties intact
```